# How to select this > a

Tags: jquery, this, target

I always forget how to select an element inside this in jQuery.
I tried something like $(this+'a') but unfurtunately that does not work correctly.
Here's a share of my code that i'm currently working with:

```
var currlink = $(this+'a').attr('href');
```

Good weeekend! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var currlink = $('a', this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an element that is contained in another element in the DOM, do this:

```
var outer = $(this)
var inner = $('a', outer)
```

Or, in short:

```
$('a', this).attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the find() function:

```
$(this).find('a').prop('href');
```

***For the time being, .prop acts almost similarly to .attr with a few discrepancies, but .attr is deprecated in the lates versions of jQuery***

You can also do

```
$(this).find('[href=http://domain.tld]');
```

The above will get an element whose href is equal to http://domain.tld